# Fetch the response from sql, store it in a object and use conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, scala, playframework

I have two sql statements to be executed with a validity check. My need is that I execute the 1st query and store the response in one object and check the object is empty or not and execute the second query if it is not empty.
So, I have tried something like

In rolerepository.scala=>

```
  override val allQuery = s"""
    select UserRoles.* from
      (select CASE rbac.roleTypeID
         ELSE rbac.name   JOIN dirNetworkInfo ni
           ON UserRoles.PersonID = ni.PersonID
              where ni.Loginname = {loginName}
                 and UserRoles.roleName in ( 'Business User ','Administrator')"""
```

(This is just some sample of the query - it is not fully written here.)
Then I map it to an object with model class written outside

```
   override def map2Object(implicit map: Map[String, Any]): 
     HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck = {    
     HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck(str("roleName"), oint("PersonID"))  }
```

Then I have written the getall method to execute the query

```
   override def getAll(implicit loginName: String): 
   Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]] = {
    doQueryIgnoreRowErrors(allQuery, "loginName" -> loginName) }
```

Then I have written the method to check whether the response from the 1st sql is empty or not. This is were I'm stuck and not able to proceed further.

```
    def method1()= {
     val getallresponse = HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck 
     getallresponse.toString
     if (getallresponse != " ")
       billingMonthCheckRepository.getrepo()
   }
```

I am getting an error (type mismatch) in last closing brace and I don't know what other logic can be used here.
Can any one of you please explain and give me some solution for this?

And i also tried to use for loop in controller but not getting how to do that.

i tried ->

```
      def getAll(implicit queryParams: QueryParams, 
     billingMonthmodel:Seq[HierarchyEntryBillingRoleCheck]): 
    Action[AnyContent] = securityService.authenticate() { implicit request 
   =>  withErrorRecovery { req =>
    toJson {
      repository.getAll(request.user.loginName)
      for {
      rolenamecheck <- billingMonthmodel

        }yield rolenamecheck
     }}}}
```

Comment: @users, I am using scala and play framework to do this, condition check my exact doubt is how to fetch the response from sql and store it in an object and check the object is empty or not using scala

Comment: @Stackoverflow users can anyone one of you please guide me here as i am stuck heavily in this code

Comment: Is there any alternative way for doing the code for this issue

Comment: Think about the return type of `method1`. It ends on an `if` statement with no `else`. So the eventual type of that method will be `Unit`, not `Future[Seq[HierarchyEntryBilling]]` as you have stated. If that is the complete method, you'll need to return something of the same type in the `else`.

Comment: @wwkudu, can you please see my new try the exact query is how to do i fetch the response from sql and store it in an object and check for empty. can you please help me on this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say which db access method you are using. (I'm assuming anorm). One way of approaching this is:

- Create a case class matching your table
- Create a parser matching your case class
- use Option (or Either) to return a row for a specific set of parameters

For example, perhaps you have:

```
case class UserRole (id:Int, loginName:String, roleName:String)
```

And then

```
object UserRole {
  val sqlFields = "ur.id, ur.loginName, ur.roleName"
  val userRoleParser = {
    get[Int]("id") ~
    get[String]("loginName") ~
    get[String]("roleName") map {
      case id ~ loginName ~ roleName => {
        UserRole(id, loginName, roleName)
      }
    }
}
...
```

The parser maps the row to your case class. The next step is creating either single row methods like `findById` or `findByLoginName` and multi-row methods, perhaps `allForRoleName` or other generic filter methods. In your case there might (assuming a single role per loginName) be something like:

```
def findByLoginName(loginName:String):Option[UserRole) = DB.withConnection { implicit c =>
  SQL(s"select $sqlFields from userRoles ur ...")
    .on('loginName -> loginName)
    .as(userRoleParser.singleOpt)
}
```

The `.as(parser...` is key. Typically, you'll need at least:

- `as(parser.singleOpt)` which returns an `Option` of your case class
- `as(parser *)` which returns a `List` of your case class (you'll need this if multiple roles could exist for a login
- `as(scalar[Long].singleOpt)` which returns an `Option[Long]` and which is handy for returning `counts` or `exists` values

Then, to eventually return to your question a little more directly, you can call your find method, and if it returns something, continue with the second method call, perhaps like this:

```
val userRole = findByLoginName(loginName)
if (userRole.isDefined)
  billingMonthCheckRepository.getrepo()
```

or, a little more idiomatically

```
findByLoginName(loginName).map { userRole =>
  billingMonthCheckRepository.getrepo()
  ...
```

I've shown the find method returning an `Option`, but in reality we find it more useful to return an `Either[String,(your case class)]`, and then the string contains the reason for failure. `Either` is cool.

On my version of play (2.3.x), the imports for the above are:

```
import play.api.db._
import play.api.Play.current
import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
```

You're going to be doing this sort of thing a lot so worth finding a set of patterns that works for you.

Comment: Really thanks for your solution it is really helping me to think in a proper way for my code on how to handle the query. Thanks A lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

WOW I don't know what's happening with the formatting here, I am really attempting to use the code formatter on the toolbar but I don't know why it won't format it, even when pressed multiple times. I invite the community to edit my code formatting because I can't figure it out. Apologies to OP.

Because I find Play's documentation to be very tough to trudge through if you're unfamiliar with it, I won't just leave a link to it only.

1. You have to inject an instance of your database into your controller. This will then give it to you as a global variable:

> ```
> @Singleton
>  class LoginRegController @Inject()(**myDB: Database**, cc: ControllerComponents ) { 
>      //  do stuff
>                  }
> ```

But, it's bad practice to actually use this connection within the controller, because the JDBC is a blocking operation, so you need to create a Model which takes the db as a parameter to a method. Don't set the constructor of the object to take the DB and store it as a field. For some reason this creates connection leaks and the connections won't release when they are done with your query. Not sure why, but that's how it is.

2. Create a Model object that you will use to execute your query. Instead of passing the DB through the object's constructor, pass it through the method you will create:

   object DBChecker {
         def attemptLogin(db:Database, password:String): String = {

   ```
   }}
   ```

   3. In your method, use the method `.withConnection { conn =>` to access your JDBC connection. So, something like this:

      object DBChecker {

      def attemptLogin(db:Database, password:String):String = {
              var username: String = ""
      db.withConnection{ conn =>

      ```
          val query:String = s"SELECT uploaded_by, date_added FROM tableName where PASSWORD = $password ;"

        val stmt = conn.createStatement()

        val qryResult:ResultSet = stmt.executeQuery(query) 
        // then iterate over your ResultSet to get the results from the query 
        if (qryResult.next()) {
          userName = qryResult.getString("uploaded_by")
      ```

      }
            }
        }
      return username
      }

// but note, please look into the use of PreparedStatement objects, doing it this way leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection.

4. In your Controller, as long as you import the object, you can then call that object's methods from your controller you made in Step 1.

   ```
       import com.path.to.object.DBChecker
   ```

   @Singleton
   class LoginRegController @Inject()(**myDB: Database**, cc: ControllerComponents ) {  def attemptLogin(pass:String) = Action {
   implicit request: Request[AnyContent] => {
           val result:String = DbChecker.attemptLogin(pass)

   ```
           // do your work with the results here 
     }
   ```

Comment: I want to thank you very much for the good solution you have given here.it is really helping me to think more. Thanks a Lot!!!